# Comparing two tables in r

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

I have a table with reference positions, like x is the start and y is the end.

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|           x         |        y         |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          10         |         35       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          58         |         89       |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Then I have another table with single positions and my goal is to check if any of the positions in this second table are in the first table, considering that the positions in this second table can be in between the col1 and col2.

```
|---------------------|
|          12         |     
|---------------------|
|          27         |       
|---------------------|
|          65         |
|---------------------|
```

How can I check this, since I can't use any of the *joins* from *dplyr*, or even the *unique*.

Comment: You can check `foverlaps` from `data.table`

Comment: @rawr which table are you talking about? I don't understand your questions.

Comment: @akrun I'll check that, thanks!

Comment: Try `df1 <- data.frame(x = c(10, 58), y = c(35, 89));df2 <- data.frame(x= c(12, 27, 65), y = c(12, 27, 65));setDT(df1, key = c('x', 'y')); setDT(df2, key = c('x', 'y'));foverlaps(df2, df1, type = "within", which = TRUE)$yid
#[1] 1 1 2`

Comment: @akrun It worked! Thank you!

Comment: @akrun That looks like a good answer to post.

Answer (score 3):

We can use `foverlaps` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
df1 <- data.frame(x = c(10, 58), y = c(35, 89))
df2 <- data.frame(x= c(12, 27, 65), y = c(12, 27, 65))
setDT(df1, key = c('x', 'y'))
setDT(df2, key = c('x', 'y'))
foverlaps(df2, df1, type = "within", which = TRUE)$yid 
#[1] 1 1 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Version 1.9.8 of `data.table` (on CRAN 25 Nov 2016) introduced *non-equi joins* which can be used instead of `foverlaps()`:

```
setDT(df1)[setDT(df2), on = .(x <= z, y >= z), which = TRUE]
```

> ```
> [1]  1  1  2 NA
> ```

Note that the second table differs from OP's data as a fourth row has been added which doesn't match any of the intervals.

#### Data

```
df1 <- data.frame(x = c(10, 58), y = c(35, 89))
df2 <- data.frame(z = c(12, 27, 65, 90))
```